# Running Python Worker on Heroku - Push Failed

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, web-scraping, worker

my scope is to run a python script (it does scrap text from websites and save it in csv files) in the cloud through cron job.
For this I chose Heroku.

I am stuck because when I try to deploy the worker I get a Push rejection.

Here is what i do:
I put my scrapit.py and Procfile ('worker: node scrapit.py') in a directory.

Then after I create an app in heroku, I send the following commands from the directory of above:

```
$ heroku login
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a app-name-on-heroku
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "nth time :("
$ git push heroku master
```

I get the following message:

> Counting objects: 41, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (41/41), 12.97 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 41 (delta 6), reused 0
>   (delta 0) remote: Compressing source files... done. remote: Building
>   source: remote:  remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack:
>   https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
>   remote:        More info:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
>   remote:  remote:  !     Push failed remote: Verifying deploy...
>   remote:  remote: !    Push rejected to app-name-on-heroku. remote:  To
>   https://git.heroku.com/app-name-on-heroku.git  ! [remote rejected]
>   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app-name-on-heroku.git'

after the error I sent this command:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

but still the push gets rejected

Comment: do I need a requirement.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Heroku buildpack specifies a [bin/detect](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect) file, which lets the platform know if that buildpack can be used with that app or not.

The python buildpack requires either: `requirements.txt`, `setup.py` or `Pipfile` to be present.
You need to create (and properly configure) one of those files to be able to have your python app built.

Comment: It worked. Now that python script is suppose to write .csv files. it seems Heroku runned it, I was expecting to get those files fetching with Git from Heroku, but nothing to be pulled shows up.. I wonder how I can get those .csv files or even if the python script actually writes them on Heroku

Comment: You may want to read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works#running-applications-on-dynos
Each heroku dyno is a container. Writing files on disk will not change your GIT repository. If you need to write a file and retrieve it, you need to store it on a system such as Amazon S3, or setup your own HTTP endpoint for it.